# copying large files over

Tags: ftp, ssh, cpanel, whm

I have a dedicated server where I host a large website. We need to do an upgrade on the website and I want to create a development copy on a testurl (on a different cpanel account) but same server.

The files are around 1GB in total size and 70,000 in number.

I have tried WS FTP pro but it has only copied 10% in around 20 hours.

What's the easiest and quickest method to create a replica on my development URL?

I am a newbie so please give detailed instructions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would think the easiest method would be this:

1. Create the new account in WHM
2. Login via SSH
3. Navigate to your existing account folder
4. Copy the files to the new account folder

This should be pretty easy for you, as long as you know how to access your server via SSH. It's pretty simple:

- Login via SSH
- Type **su** and enter your root password (this is only necessary if you SSH into your server using an account other than root - a good practice, in my opinion)
- Find and navigate to your source account. I'm assuming you're probably setup to have your web accounts in the **/home** folder, so try typing something like **cd /home/source_folder**
- Once you're in the correct source directory, type **cp -R * /home/destination_folder**

That's pretty much it. The -R option recursively copies all the files from your source to your destination, and if you're copying a HUGE number of files, you might consider adding **--verbose** after the **-R** option so you can see it working. I apologize in advance if I've gone a little more granular than needed.

Comment: The question is asking the quicker way to transfer the files.